# C++ - Прохождение по вектору состоящему из объектов пользовательского класса

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пишу маленькую программку на C++.
Задача следующая.
Необходимо определить класс, хранящий имя человека и целочисленное значение.
Далее, на стандартный вход подаётся два слова name и score, например:

```
John 18
```

И они сохраняются в объекте класса, как имя и целочисленное значение соответственно. И после, этот объект помещается в вектор.

Если подается:

```
NoName 0
```

То в конце необходимо вывести строка за строкой, все имена и соответствующие им числа, а так же выходим из программы.
Если вводим имя которое уже есть среди объектов, говорим, что нельзя и идём дальше.

Вот мой код:

```
// Examples.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Name_value
{
public:
    Name_value(string n, int s) :name(n), score(s) {}

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    int getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }

private:
    string name;
    int score;
};


bool check_duplicates(vector<Name_value> &names, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        if (names[i].getName == name)
        {
            cerr << "Error: This name already exists.\n";
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


void keep_window_open()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return;
}


int main()
{
    string name;
    int score;

    vector<Name_value> vector_names;


    cout << "Please, input name and score!\n";
    while (cin >> name >> score)
    {
        Name_value name_score = Name_value(name, score);

        if (name_score.getName() == "NoName" && name_score.getScore() == 0) break;
        if (check_duplicates(vector_names, name)) continue;

        vector_names.push_back(name_score);
        cout << "Added\n";
    }

    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < vector_names.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vector_names[i].getName << " " << vector_names[i].getScore << '\n';
    }

    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

    keep_window_open();
}
```

Получаю следующие сообщения:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Examples, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Examples.cpp
1>c:\users\saibo\source\repos\examples\examples\examples.cpp(35): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\saibo\source\repos\examples\examples\examples.cpp(37): error C3867: 'Name_value::getName': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\saibo\source\repos\examples\examples\examples.cpp(37): error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual 
studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\system_error(374): note: could be 'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\system_error(368): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\system_error(362): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\system_error(356): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\exception(329): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\exception(324): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\exception(319): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xstring(3877): note: or       'bool std::operator ==<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &) noexcept'
1>c:\users\saibo\source\repos\examples\examples\examples.cpp(37): note: while trying to match the argument list '(overloaded-function, std::string)'
1>c:\users\saibo\source\repos\examples\examples\examples.cpp(80): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\saibo\source\repos\examples\examples\examples.cpp(82): error C3867: 'Name_value::getName': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\saibo\source\repos\examples\examples\examples.cpp(82): error C3867: 'Name_value::getScore': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
1>Done building project "Examples.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Жалуется на следующие фрагменты:

```
if (names[i].getName == name) // строка 37
{
    cerr << "Error: This name already exists.\n";
    return true;
}
```

И этот:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector_names.size(); i++)
{
    cout << vector_names[i].getName << " " << vector_names[i].getScore << '\n'; // строка 82
}
```

В C++ - новичок. Не могу понять смысл данных замечаний. Буду рад подсказке!

Comment: Лог компиляции можно найти в окошке `Output`, вставьте его как текст вместо картинки. Ну а `getName` - это функция, для ее вызова нужны скобки `getName()`

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к функции класса `Name_Value` как члену объекта. А надо как к методу объекта `names[i].getName()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов функции в языке С++ делается при помощи оператора `()`. Всякий раз, когда вы хотите вызвать функцию, необходимо использовать оператор `()`. Без этого - никак.

При этом у вас в одном месте все написано правильно

```
name_score.getName()
```

а в другом вдруг

```
vector_names[i].getName
```

Куда и почему вдруг пропал оператор `()` во втором случае?

Comment: Это все автодополнение MVS :)

Comment: По всей видимости, незаметил :.D
Пожалуй, пора идти спать

Answer (score -5):

```
if (names[i].getName == name)
```

Нет скобок.

```
cout << vector_names[i].getName << " " << vector_names[i].getScore << '\n';
```

Нет скобок.

Comment: В чем смысл повторить ответ другого человека с более плохим оформлением?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker В чем смысл оставлять комментарии, ортогональные действительности?

Comment: принятый ответ перечитайте, может, что-нибудь и поймете :)

Comment: Ну кагбе во-первых, в принятом ответе процитировано одно место, где пропущены скобки, а я привел оба, чтоб два раза не бегать; а во-вторых — ура, эксперты по оформлению приехали.

Comment: Вы "кагбе" просто ткнули на ошибку, "Нет скобок.", автор оригинального поста объяснил, в чем конкретно ошибка и как ее исправить. Может, автор вопроса не поймет, куда ставить скобки, вы об этом не подумали? Какая тогда ценность вашего ответа? Если можете дополнить ответ - дополните его, бегать за плюсами повторяя чужие ответы - такое себе занятие.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Ну я как-то не осмелился предположить, что автор безглазый дурачок и не увидит ошибку даже после того, как я сузил контекст со всего файла до одной строки. Хотя если вы так уверены...